# Apple Enterprise Developer Account Query

Tags: apple, enterprise-development

My employer is looking to purchase an enterprise account in the belief that it will enable us to develop and distribute apps for large clients of ours - however online it clearly states that the Enterprise account should only be used to distribute apps to the employees of the company that own the account.

So my question is this: If we want to distribute in-house apps to "Company X" should we ask them to purchase an Enterprise account to distribute the app we made for them, or do we buy the account under our organisation instead?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Surely the best people to ask are Apple?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question for Apple support.

Comment: Downvoting a >4 year old migrated question, thanks guys.

Comment: @Luke Downvotes aren't personal. We're just trying to clean up off-topic questions so people stop taking them as evidence that these kinds of questions are worth asking here. If you like you can save us some trouble by deleting this yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the reply Kevin - I took your advice.

Answer: The company that wishes to distribute the app in-house would be required to purchase the enterprise account and then grant the developer access.